# Is this differentiation correct?

Tags: derivatives, calculus-of-variations

$J(x,y')=\int_1^2 xy'(x)+(y'(x))^2dx = \int_1^2{f(y,y^\prime,x)}$

Need to find $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^\prime})$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^\prime}=x+2y'(x)$

$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^\prime})=1$

Is this correct, or what is the right solution?

Comment: I guess this is calculus of variations? And the integrand is what you are considering as $f(y,y^\prime, x)$? I think you meant to type ${d\over dx}({\partial f\over\partial y^\prime})$ rather than ${d\over dx}({\partial f\over\partial y})$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. For that part I got x from the first term in the sum and brought down the exponent in the second part of the sum. i.e. analogous to $5x+x^2$ differentiated as 5+2x

Comment: When you do ${d\over dx}(x + 2y^\prime)$, you need to remember that $y^\prime$ is a function of $x$, so the result is $1 + 2y^{\prime\prime}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do ${d\over dx}(x + 2y^\prime)$, you need to remember that $y^\prime$ is a function of $x$, so the result is $1 + 2y^{\prime\prime}(x)$.

Comment: Ok, and I am curious, what would happen if $\partial f/ \partial y$ was x*2y'(x) instead?

Comment: Would this be 2y'(x)*1*2y"(x)?

Comment: Then it would be product rule: $(x)(2y^{\prime\prime}(x)) + (1)(2y^\prime(x))$.